# StackOfIntegers Giving Weird Results

Tags: java, stack

I have an issue making code that returns the prime factorization of an integer. I know that my code is giving the right factors, but I am required to use the StackOfIntegers class.

The StackOfIntegers class does not seem to handle duplicates well. When I input 120, the prime factors 5, 3, and 2 are returned. This output is missing 2 other 2's.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        StackOfIntegers stack = new StackOfIntegers(1);
        int factor = 2;
        while (true) {
            if (number % factor == 0) {
                number = number / factor;
                stack.push(factor);
            }
            if (factor > number) {
                break;
            }
            if (number % factor != 0) {
                factor++;
            }
            if (number < 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nPrime Factors: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < stack.getSize(); i++) {
            System.out.println(stack.pop());
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

```
class StackOfIntegers {
    private int[] elements;
    private int size;
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 16;

    /** Construct a stack with the default capacity 16 */
    public StackOfIntegers() {
        this(MAX_SIZE);
    }

    /** Construct a stack with the specified maximum capacity */
    public StackOfIntegers(int capacity) {
        elements = new int[capacity];
    }

    /** Push a new integer into the top of the stack */
    public int push(int value) {
        if (size >= elements.length) {
            int[] temp = new int[elements.length * 2];
            System.arraycopy(elements, 0, temp, 0, elements.length);
            elements = temp;
        }

        return elements[size++] = value;
    }

    /** Return and remove the top element from the stack */
    public int pop() {
        return elements[--size];
    }

    /** Return the top element from the stack */
    public int peek() {
        return elements[size - 1];
    }

    /** Test whether the stack is empty */
    public boolean empty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

    /** Return the number of elements in the stack */
    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are incrementing `i` but still comparing it to the *current* size of your stack, which is decreasing in each iteration as well.

You can store the size of the stack in a new variable `size` prior to the `for` loop, or you can just have a `while` loop, and while the stack is not empty, `pop` and print an element.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution.